# Formulate quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Here is an equation $$r^3-5r^2+8r-4=0$$

Is there a way I can formulate a quadratic equation from this?

Sorry if the question seem dumb, I am stuck and I can't figure a way out.

Comment: Do you see any obvious roots? That is, try substituting some small numbers and see if you find a root. If you find a root $a$, then $r-a$ divides the polynomial, so you can reduce it to a quadratic.

Comment: $r=1$ is a root. Which means that you can divide your cubic by $(r-1)$ and get a quadratic, which may have other roots

Comment: An explanation will help, sir. Am getting to learn Mathematics, it is not my strong point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (which actually has a very simple proof, as shown in Wikipedia), if $r^3-5r^2+8r-4$ has a rational root, then it must be one of $-4,-2,-1,1,2,4$.

By checking, you'll find that $1$ is a root (actually, $2$ is also a root).

Therefore the polynomial $r^3-5r^2+8r-4$ is divisible by $r-1$. Now you can use long division (with your preferred method). Here is one way you can divide:

$$r^3-5r^2+8r-4=(r-1)r^2-4r^2+8r-4$$

$$=(r-1)r^2-(r-1)4r+4r-4$$

$$=(r-1)r^2-(r-1)4r+(r-1)4$$

$$=(r-1)\left(r^2-4r+4\right)=(r-1)(r-2)^2$$

Comment: From this please, what will then be my Co-efficient for A,B, C?

Comment: @Diamond: what coefficients do you mean?

Comment: ax^2+bx+c = 0, I am kind of lost